# What to use if i want to repeat set of parameters in php libcurl session

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do multiple things in curl and obviously some parameters in each step will be the same... should i use [curl copy handle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-copy-handle.php) or [curl setopt array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php)? As far as i understand both do the same thing... or i'm getting something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see any benefit to using one or the other. The only difference I can see is *curl_setopt_array()* is only available as of php 5.1.3.

*curl_setopt_array()* does seem somewhat cleaner as opposed to using a bunch of *curl_setopt()*